# jQuery: Check if window is smaller than x units other than pixels (e.g. em, rem)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass, media-queries

Sounds trivial but how can I actually check this? I have the following breakpoints in SASS:

```
$width_breakpoints: (
        small: 39.9375em,
        medium: 40em,
        large: 76em
);
```

Now I want to check the following (Pseudo-Code):

```
if($(window).width() < 39.9375em) {
    // add current-mode-mobile class to a certain element
}
```

How can I actually check if the width is smaller than X em or X rem or X percent?

Comment: What you need get the 39.9375em in pixel?

Comment: `em` depends on the `font-size` of the `parent` element, `rem` depends on the font-size of the `body` . Just get the font-size you need and use it in the javascript/jquery condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IE10+:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 39.9375em)").matches) {
  /* the viewport is at least 39.9375 em wide */
} else {
  /* the viewport is less than 39.9375 em wide */
}
```

Comment: IE < 10 is gonna die. Broad support indeed: https://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia .

Comment: I didn't know about this matchMedia, it looks really nice.

Comment: Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that does not even needs jQuery.

```
var widthInEm =  window.innerWidth /
          parseFloat(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('body'))['font-size'])

if(widthInEm < 39.9375) {
   // add current-mode-mobile class to a certain element
}
```

Comment: Therefore the width in pixels must be converted to the desired unit or vice versa? Sounds like an acceptable idea i ll check it and give feedback.